# I need to run a progress bar using a time in a DLL C#

Tags: c#, dll, timer, progress-bar, invoke

It seems I need to use a timer in a separate thread, since a time is not working if i use a normal time.  So i did the following, however while it stops at the Invoke statement the progress bar does not change value!

```
public partial class LoadingForm : Form
{
    System.Threading.Timer t;

    public LoadingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar.Maximum = 100;

        t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 500);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object e)
    {
        //time is here
        progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value++));
    }

    private void timerTick()
    {
        //this is what i need to do !!!!
        if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum) { progressBar.Value = 0; }
        progressBar.Value++;
    }
}
```

(if it works ideally I would want to be able to call timerTick() in the Invoke statement)

Comment: I think you may want a `DispatcherTimer` object. See documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You are not calling tinerTick nor have you used it in a delegate

Comment: @Aldert, no at that stage I was trying `progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Value++));`

Comment: @ryan-wilson, `DispatcherTimer` is not working in a DLL, the timer event is not fired.

Comment: The problem seems to be related that the current thread is BLOCKED !